# How to automatically sign in user from HttpModule

Tags: 2013, login, http-module

If a request to a certain site collection comes in from an anonymous user, I want to do a sign in as a specific user. For this I would like to use a HTTP module. So basically I want to do something like this:

```
private void ContextAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
    {
        //Sign in here
    }
}
```

How can I do the actual signing in?

Comment: :) if you login as anonymous , how can you login as specific user ? i think you need to reframe question .

Comment: I don't want to log in AS anonymous, I want to log in as a specific user if a request is made by a user that is not (yet) logged in. This would be the same user every time, think of it as a dedicated guest account or something. Obviously the details are simplified for this question as they are not relevant. What's important is: "How do I do a Sharepoint login via code?" and "It must work in the AuthenticateRequest handler of an HTTP module".

Comment: check answer , this should give u a start

Answer (score 0):

PS : https://serverfault.com/questions/17782/logging-in-as-another-user-in-sharepoint/17979#17979

```
class LoginModule {
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
 context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(UglyHack);
}

void UglyHack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 HttpCookie wannabe = (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_sp_admin_wanna_be_user"]);
 if (wannabe != null && SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin)
 {
     SPWeb cw = SPContext.Current.Web;
     typeof(SPWeb).GetField("m_CurrentUser", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(
                    SPContext.Current.Web,
                    cw.AllUsers[wannabe.Value]);
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my situation (still no user signed in after code has run) and it would indeed be a really ugly hack if it did - setting the current user using reflection.